# Two data in same column display above/below when create CSV file in stylesheet using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, stylesheet

[image]

I am create CSV file using rails coding but i have issue two contact data display in same column in continue.. so data not display in good format.

Currently display data like:

```
-------------------------------
|email:1@gmail.comphone:3453453|   
-------------------------------
```

I want to display like:

```
-------------------
|email:1@gmail.com|
|phone:3453453    | 
-------------------
```

in same column.

I am using below code:

```
     dpwn_text = "#{t('email')}: #{d.contact}" + "#{t('PhoneNo')}: #{d.phoneno}" 

     tmp_file = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/temp.csv"

     File.open(tmp_file, 'wb') do |f|  
       f.write dpwn_text
     end

     send_data(dpwn_text, :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => "publishers.csv")
     return
```

Comment: how do you generate this files? Show code

Comment: i added code in my main questions.. please refer it..

Answer (score 0):

```
 dpwn_text = "#{t('email')}: #{d.contact}" + "\n#{t('PhoneNo')}: #{d.phoneno}"
```

but this format is not csv..
if you want to make it csv (coma seperated value) then it should look like this:

```
##contacts.csv
# email; phone
email1; 123
email2; 32434
email3; ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to display in single cell. Using '\n' it's make a new cell.

Comment: then please specify what excactly you want.. its not csv, and you showed only the code without the border

Comment: Please refer image which i uploaded in my main question.

Comment: then you have to use a correct csv format and my solution above.. then it should work